# Fee rest service for currency converter implementation.

Tags: web-services, rest

I am using AEM to create new website where I am looking for some open source currency converter service (wen service, restful) available over net. 
The way I want to implement currency conversion is like fourseasons site when you go to room booking, when I select USD all figure on my page in INR should convert to USD.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

Here is Fee rest service for currency convertation.

http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=INR